# Caveat on usage of logical operators in if .. else if .. else

Tags: r, comparison-operators

This is not a question. I would like to cover a scarcely documented part of R.

```
a <- 0.3-0.1 # should be 0.2

b <- 0.7-0.5 # should also be 0.2
```

However, due to floating point representation,

```
a==b
[1] FALSE
```

From the documentation, there are two correct ways to boolean check the equality:

```
isTRUE(all.equal(a,b))

identical(all.equal(a,b), TRUE)
```

What is not immediately obvious is that if one wants to check all of `>`, `<`, `==` in one `if .. else if .. else if` structure, then the test of equality *must* be conducted prior to the other two tests. Since either of
`a > b` or `a < b` can unpredictably turn out to be TRUE - again, due to floating point numerical fuzzyness.

Example of unwanted behaviour:

```
if (a < b)
{
    print('a smaller than b')

} else if (a > b) {
    print('a greater than b')

} else if (isTRUE(all.equal(a,b))) {
    print('a equal b')
}

[1] "a smaller than b"
```

I hope this will help.

Kind regards,
luca

Comment: A better way to post this is to ask it as a question: "Why do I get this result when I do such and such?". You can then answer your own question. That is better than just writing an answer disguised as a question ;)

Comment: @nico maybe the OP don't have enough votes to answer his own question:)

Comment: @agstudy: is there a rep limit to do that?

Comment: @nico Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours.

Comment: FYI:  `isTRUE(x)` is a function that evaluates to `identical(x, TRUE)`

Answer (score 4):

If I run your code, I get

```
> [1] "a greater than b"
```

This is not unexpected.  Taking a tip from the first circle of the [R inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) and looking at more digits

```
> print(c(a,b,a-b), digits=20)
[1] 1.9999999999999998335e-01 1.9999999999999995559e-01
[3] 2.7755575615628913511e-17
```

so it is no surprise R thinks `a > b` is TRUE.

To deal with this, you could have written something like

```
if        (a < b & ! isTRUE(all.equal(a, b))) {
    print('a smaller than b')

} else if (a > b & ! isTRUE(all.equal(a, b))) {
    print('a greater than b')

} else if (a == b |  isTRUE(all.equal(a, b))) {
    print('a equals b')
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what the OP meant as a solution:

```
if (isTRUE(all.equal(a, b))) {
    print('a equals b')
} else if (a > b) {
    print('a greater than b')
} else if (a < b) {
   print('a smaller than b')
}
```

By ruling out `all.equal`-ity first, you can then trust that `<` and `>` will do what was intended. This way, there is no need for repeated usage of `all.equal`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can include a threshold value.

```
thresh <- 1e-12

if (a - b > thresh)        {
    print('a greater than b')
} else if (b - a > thresh) {
    print('a smaller than b')
} else {
    print('a equals b')
}
```

Comment: `all.equal` does that for you. You just need to use it first.